# chrome.cookies.get showing either undefined or throwing error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

`chrome.cookies.get({url:"http://www.dahotre.com", name:"userid"}, function(){})` shows `undefined` in the console.

If I skip the optional empty function(), it throws an error.
`chrome.cookies.get({url:"http://www.dahotre.com", name:"userid"})` shows `Uncaught Error: Parameter 2 is required.`

And if I use `function(Cookie c){}` as the second param, it throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Following is the `permissions` line from my `manifest.json`:

`"permissions": [ "cookies", "http://www.dahotre.com/"],`

When I inspect the cookies in my browser, I can most certainly find a cookie from the site `www.dahotre.com` with a name=userid and a integer content.

How to access this cookie in a chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
chrome.cookies.get({url:"http://www.dahotre.com", name:"userid"}, function(cookies){
    console.log(cookies);
});
```

Your `function(Cookie c){}` was a nice try, but JavaScript is dynamically typed language and those verbose types are used only for documentantion purpose.

Comment: Thanks hamczu. I can't believe the amount of time I have wasted in this.